# Set default values for jQuery UI Autocomplete with multi selection

Tags: jquery, select, user-interface, autocomplete, multi-select

I am trying to use the jQuery UI Autocomplete multiselect to edit a category (one of 200 categories to be accurate).
The high number of possible categories is why I would like to use the autoselect feature of the jQuery UI. However, I could not figure out how to set the predefined categories.

Look at the Autocomplete multiselect Input in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sgxKJ/

It does what I want to do. But I like to find a way to pre define one or two elements (Say "Java" and "AppleScript" in the example) while loading the page.
How can I do that in a Java Script of the page?
Would it be possible to do this in the same ".autocomplete({" function that does already exist?

As css I use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="autocomplete/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css">
```

I also use the following css:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300);

body, html {
    font-family: Calibri,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
    font-family: Ubuntu;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h1.has-sub {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

ul {
    list-style: disc;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    margin-top: .5em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

p {
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}

p.hint {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: .8em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #555;
}

p.hint:before {
    content: "Hint: "
}

header {
    background: rgb(76,76,76); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1) 1%, rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,rgba(76,76,76,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(63,63,63,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1) 1%,rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1) 1%,rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1) 1%,rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#3f3f3f',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1) 1%,rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    padding: .2em 1.2em;
    font-family: Ubuntu;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #999;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #333;
    text-align: right;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

header span {
    margin-left: .3em;
    font-size: .6em;
}

article {
    padding: 20px;
}

label {
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 1.7;
}

.columns {
    padding: 2em;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 5em;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px dashed #ccc;
    column-count: 2;
    column-rule: 1px dashed #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


.columns > h2 {
    -webkit-column-break-before: always;
}

#header {
    height: 10px;
    background: rgb(76,76,76); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1) 1%, rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,rgba(76,76,76,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(63,63,63,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1) 1%,rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1) 1%,rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1) 1%,rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#3f3f3f',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1) 1%,rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%); /* W3C */
}

#body {
    padding: 20px;
}

input.vanilla,
.ui-autocomplete-multiselect.ui-state-default {
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 3px 3px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: text;
}

input.vanilla {
    line-height: 1.7;
    padding: 2px 5px;
}

.ui-autocomplete-multiselect .ui-autocomplete-multiselect-item .ui-icon {
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-autocomplete-multiselect .ui-autocomplete-multiselect-item {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.ui-autocomplete-multiselect input {
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    height: auto;
    margin: 2px;
    overflow: visible;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}

input.vanilla:focus,
.ui-autocomplete-multiselect.ui-state-active {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #7ea4c7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(50,150,255,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(50,150,255,0.5);
    -khtml-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(50,150,255,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(50,150,255,0.5);
}

.ui-autocomplete {
    border-top: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

As Input I use this in the HTML part:

```
<input id="AutoMultiSelect" class="vanilla" type="text" value="" size="40" />
```

The jQuery Versions I use are:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="autocomplete/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="autocomplete/js/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js"></script>
```

And the following script is used at the end of the body part of my html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($, undefined) {
    if (typeof $.uix !== "object") { $.uix = {}; }
    var ac = $.ui.autocomplete.prototype;
    var _super = {
        _create: ac._create,
        _destroy: ac._destroy,
        _resizeMenu: ac._resizeMenu,
        _suggest: ac._suggest,
        search: ac.search,
        open: ac.open,
        close: ac.close
    };
    ac = $.extend({}, ac, {
        options: $.extend({}, ac.options, {
            multiselect: false,
            triggerChar: false
        }),
        _create: function(){
            var self = this,
                o = self.options;
            _super._create.apply(self);

            if (o.multiselect) {
                self.selectedItems = { };           
                self.multiselect = $("<div></div>")
                    .addClass("ui-autocomplete-multiselect ui-state-default ui-widget")
                    .css("width", self.element.width())
                    .insertBefore(self.element)
                    .append(self.element)
                    .bind("click.autocomplete", function(){
                        self.element.focus();
                    });

                var fontSize = parseInt(self.element.css("fontSize"), 10);
                function autoSize(e){
                    // Hackish autosizing
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.width(1).width(this.scrollWidth+fontSize-1);
                };

                var kc = $.ui.keyCode;
                self.element.bind({
                    "keydown.autocomplete": function(e){
                        if ((this.value === "") && (e.keyCode == kc.BACKSPACE)) {
                            var prev = self.element.prev();
                            delete self.selectedItems[prev.text()];
                            prev.remove();
                        }
                    },
                    // TODO: Implement outline of container
                    "focus.autocomplete blur.autocomplete": function(){
                        self.multiselect.toggleClass("ui-state-active");
                    },
                    "keypress.autocomplete change.autocomplete focus.autocomplete blur.autocomplete": autoSize
                }).trigger("change");

                // TODO: There's a better way?
                o.select = o.select || function(e, ui) {
                    $("<div></div>")
                        .addClass("ui-autocomplete-multiselect-item")
                        .text(ui.item.label)
                        .append(
                            $("<span></span>")
                                .addClass("ui-icon ui-icon-close")
                                .click(function(){
                                    var item = $(this).parent();
                                    delete self.selectedItems[item.text()];
                                    item.remove();
                                })
                        )
                        .insertBefore(self.element);

                    self.selectedItems[ui.item.label] = ui.item;
                    self._value("");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return this;
        },
        _resizeMenu: function(){
            if (this.options.multiselect) {
                var ul = this.menu.element;
                ul.outerWidth( Math.max(
                    ul.width( "" ).outerWidth(),
                    this.multiselect.outerWidth()
                ) );
            } else {
                _super._resizeMenu.apply(this);
            }
        },
        _suggest: function( items ) {
            var elm = this.element;
            // Override this.element with our multiselect for proper positioning
            this.element = this.options.multiselect ? this.multiselect : this.element;
            _super._suggest.apply(this, [items]);   
            this.element = elm;
        },
        search: function( value, event ) {
            value = value != null ? value : this._value();
            if (this.options.triggerChar) {
                if (value.substring(0,1) != this.options.triggerChar) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    value = value.substring(1);
                }
            }
            return _super.search.apply(this, [value, event]);
        },
        // Borrowed from 1.9
        _value: function( value ) {
            return this.valueMethod.apply( this.element, arguments );
        },
        // Borrowed from 1.9
        valueMethod: function() {
            var result = this[this.is( "input" ) ? "val" : "text"].apply(this, arguments);
            this.trigger("change");
            return result;
        }
    });

    $.uix.autocomplete = ac;
    $.widget("uix.autocomplete", $.uix.autocomplete);
})(jQuery);

var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
];
</script>

<script>
    $( "#AutoMultiSelect" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        multiselect: true
    });
</script>
```

P.S. I am a newbie here and have tried all the answers in stackoverflow I could find. However, none seemed to work with the code above.

Comment: Have you tried with .val("defaultValue")  on textbox.?

Comment: Yes I have tried  $( "#AutoMultiSelect" ).val( 'Java' ); but it is not working. It ads a "Jav" as a text in the field. However it does not place it as if it was a manually selected item. It's only text.

Comment: you have to add a css class too ..for the value inside the box ..

Comment: You are right this was missing. I edited my post and added this css. However, this does not alter the behaviour. So is there no way to just add the value and then run one or two events (say "change" for example) to get the behaviour I need?

Comment: Do you have an example of how to trigger the css format for a text set with .val() in the input? I still can´t figure it out.